# I am adding mdbootstrap modal to my angular project and it showing error

Tags: mdbootstrap

i got this error:-
Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "mdbModal" ("k)="basicModal.show()" mdbWavesEffect>Launch demo modal